# Exceeded soft private memory limit of 128 MB with X MB after servicing Y requests total

Tags: google-app-engine, memory, task-queue, rate, bucket

I get the dreaded Exceeded-memory-error in my App Engine-application that have a Cron-job pushing multiple small tasks to a queue.

I don't think any single task should trigger the critical error so I'm guessing that they are somehow connected; sharing the memory that is lacking. 
I'm running my queue with a Maximum Rate of 4/s and a Bucket Size of 5.

How can I be sure and what can/should I do?

```
Exceeded soft private memory limit of 128 MB with 131 MB after servicing 18 requests total
Exceeded soft private memory limit of 128 MB with 128 MB after servicing 1933 requests total
Exceeded soft private memory limit of 128 MB with 153 MB after servicing 3697 requests total
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When a task have been executing for 10 min, it will terminate. The error-message for this can be somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You can monitor memory instance usage like this (I'm assuming Python):

```
from google.appengine.api.runtime import memory_usage
logging.warn("Memory usage:  %d MB" % (memory_usage().current()))
```

You could do the following:

1. Decrease task rate.
2. Use instances with larger memory.
3. Modify your code to be more efficient.  I recently had this problem with a task in a task queue, so I made each task smaller and then daisy chained a new task to continue the work.  When a task finishes, the garbage collector should immediately clean up for you.